# PDO Query Not Showing Data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to migrate a site from some poorly written MySQLi to clean PDO.

I have looked at three similar questions and their answers, and this is a straightforward question, but none of them are giving me results. Here's my code:

```
$state = "Alaska";

//trying to implement PDO here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE state = ? ORDER BY type";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array($state));

/* 
this was the old, successfully working way before
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE state = '$state' ORDER BY type";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
*/
```

Previous questions on this site show me answers that look like my PDO implementation, yet mine doesn't work. I have made sure the PDO class exists and that the extension is loaded.

If you see the error, let me know!

Comment: There's a lot of unknowns here. Have you connected properly? Do you fetch the results? What do you do with the presumed fetched result?

Comment: ...and using the same api. Not still `mysqli_` is it?

Comment: *"If you see the error, let me know!"* - not for what you posted and probably more like what you didn't post; the connection used and besides what's been said by @Qirel - Question's unclear.

Comment: You're right, I'm sure it's the way I'm fetching the results. Is PDO::FETCH_ASSOC the preferred way to do it?

Comment: `try{ $result->execute(array($state)); } catch(PDOException $e){ exit($e->getMessage()); }` and see what it returns.

Comment: I posted an answer with a complete example of [PDO prepared statements with exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214516/pdo-global-instance-new-pdo-its-possible/45216199#45216199). Maybe it answers to some of your questions. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two, aside from difference in libraries, is that one is using a direct `query()` (the `mysqli_*`), while the other is using a prepared statement. Those are handled a bit different, regardless which API is running.

When using MySQLi, doing

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

would have `$result` be a mysqli-result object, which holds the data. You can use `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()` on that to fetch the data. However, when you're using `PDO::prepare()`, your `$result` variable will be a PDOStatement - which is a bit different. You'll need to run a `fetch()` method on it first, and then you can use the return-value of it, as such

```
$state = "Alaska";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE state = ? ORDER BY type";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($state));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note that I've changed the names of your variables. Now `$result` is an array (if there are any results fetched), which you can use as you normally do when fetching associative-arrays. If there are no results, `PDOStatement::fetch()` will return a boolean `false`.

```
var_dump($result['state']);
```

You can loop the `fetch()` method as

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

if you expect more than one row. Use `$result` as you would without looping, as shown above.

Note that this assumes a valid PDO-connection. Beware that you **cannot** interchange any MySQL libraries, `mysql_`, `mysqli_*` and PDO are all different animals in the zoo.

- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: OP has *more* than enough *lol* if that fails... I wouldn't know.

Comment: Hope that'll clear it up for OP. If it doesn't, we'll need "*a few*" more details. ;-)

Comment: Given the time lapse and not seeing a green tick, I think we/you just might.

Comment: Nope, that did it - was playing around with some PDO things. Appreciate the help and explanation! I'm clearly a grassroots PDO noob.